# What is the encoding method in this trz file, and how to decode it

Tags: xml, decode

In the following xml file, what is the coding method for the data field. The string is "3ATcBNwE3ATcBA=="

How to decode it?

Thank you very much.

```
<unix_time>1485991810</unix_time>
<data_id>16</data_id>
<interval>60</interval>
<count>5</count>
<data>3ATcBNwE3ATcBA==</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (the `==` padding at the end sort of gives it away).  It decodes into 0xdc04 0xdc04 0xdc04 0xdc04 0xdc04.